# Install pear : sha1 signature could not be verified broken signature

Tags: php, pear

I want to install pear on my Windows 7, but I got the error :

```
phar "D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\go-pear.phar" 
SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature
Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php): failed to open stream: phar "D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\go-pear.phar" SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature in D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\go-pear.phar on line 1236
Call Stack:
0.0270     524984   1. {main}() D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\go-pear.phar:0**
```

I configured my `php.ini` with :

```
phar.require_hash = Off
```

And I cant find any solution to this problem.

Comment: Before trying to suppress the signature check, have you given the thought _why_ there is a signature to be verified any attention? Where did you get that software from?

Comment: I get it on the official website of Pear.
Here :  http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?